# Row-level formulas not visible for all profiles

Tags: custom-reports, visibility, report-formula

I have a row-level formula defined on my report on a field which is accessible to only a couple of profiles including Admin. The weird thing is that the formula  is visible only to the Admin profile even though the FLS on the field is defined correctly for the other profiles.

I could in fact define the same new Row-level formula by logging in as a user with one of those profiles on which it wasn't visible.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but you could also try to create a formula field on the object itself and set the FLS accordingly there

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps, when I encountered this problem.  Certain profiles were unable to see the row-level formula because they did not have read permission on one of the fields referenced in the formula.